# Adobe Flash CS5 for iPhone game development?

Tags: iphone, flash, flash-cs5

Since Apple loosened their terms again, is it posible to develop a game in FLash CS5 and publish it on the Apple App Store?

Are there actually any real apps / games on the App Store that were build on Flash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Adobe Labs](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/)

and the [FAQ](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Packager_for_iPhone%3aDeveloper_FAQ)